# Subclass inheriting variables from Parent (Python)

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I'm a little confused as to how to directly inherit variables from a parent class' `__init__` function. For instance, I have the following:

```
class BaselineModels:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logpath = './log/models/'
        self.mpath = './models/'
```

I then create a subclass which has its own `__init__` and calls `super()`, but I can't seem to access `self.mpath`. I know it's something to do with `self` being bound to the class instance, but how would I go about achieving this functionality as I have a good number of subclasses for which I don't want to replicate these path variables.

The reason I want this is that I call functions from this parent class from within my subclass which uses the parent's class `self` variables (`csv_to_df` is a member of the parent class):

```
def csv_to_df(self) -> tuple:
        """Reads in CSV file declared in __init__ (self.rpath) and converts it to a number of Pandas DataFrames.

        Returns:
            tuple: Returns tuple of Pandas DataFrames; user features, item features and 
                interactions between items.

        """

        df = pd.read_csv(self.rpath, sep='\t')
        return df
```

Calling this from the subclass results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_baselines.py", line 480, in <module>
    als.run()
  File "model_baselines.py", line 366, in run
    df = self.csv_to_df()
  File "model_baselines.py", line 46, in csv_to_df
    df = pd.read_csv(self.rpath, sep='\t')
AttributeError: 'ALS' object has no attribute 'rpath'
```

Subclass definition

```
class ALS(BaselineModels):
    def __init__(self):
        super()
        self.model_name = 'als'

    def run(self):
        df = self.csv_to_df()
```

I call `als.run()` from the bottom the file.

**EDIT:** Updated to include subclass definition

Comment: Strange, the way you describe your subclass, I would expect it to be able to access mpath. Please provide a [mcve] that includes the subclass' definition.

Comment: @Kevin I've updated my question to include the subclass definition and some other information.

Comment: `mpath` vs `rpath`?

Comment: it looks like the AttributeError is on `df = pd.read_csv(self.rpath, sep='\t')` which is calling `self.rpath`  which as far as I can tell is not set anywhere, do you get a similar error for `self.mpath` ?

Comment: @kuomi You can inherit the function using super function. Like  super(<base class name>, self).__init__() this way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to call the `__init__()` method of the `super()` object.  Something like this:

```
class BaselineModels:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logpath = './log/models/'
        self.mpath = './models/'

class ALS(BaselineModels):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model_name = 'als'

    def run(self):
        df = self.csv_to_df()


als = ALS()
als.mpath
# returns:
'./models/'
```

Comment: Ah, I thought `super()` took care of the initialisation here. This works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this method also.

```
class BaselineModels:
    def __init__(self):
        self.logpath = './log/models/'
        self.mpath = './models/'

class ALS(BaselineModels):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ALS, self).__init__()
        self.model_name = 'als'

    def run(self):
        df = self.csv_to_df()


als = ALS()
als.mpath
# returns:
'./models/'
```